# AngularJS after login redirecting works only after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The issue is persistent with both chrome and firefox.

I am trying to integrate two samples from codepen one for signing in and second one loading google map.

I am observing after login the url is being changed but it's loading empty page. If I do a page refresh it's loading the map otherwise not.

What can be the issue. The issue is persistent with both chrome and firefox so it's not specific to any chrome extension. I didn't find the mentioned extension in my chrome as mentioned in some other thread.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is my code for app.js, style.css, index.html :

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


  $stateProvider
    .state('signin', {
      url: '/sign-in',
      templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
      controller: 'SignInCtrl'
    })
    .state('forgotpassword', {
      url: '/forgot-password',
      templateUrl: 'templates/forgot-password.html'
    })
    .state('tabs', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: '/facts',
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/facts.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: '/facts2',
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/facts2.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: '/about',
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/about.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: '/navstack',
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/nav-stack.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: '/contact',
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/contact.html'
        }
      }
    });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sign-in');

})

.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state, $location) {

  $scope.signIn = function(user) {
    console.log('Sign-Innnn', user);
    $state.go('tabs.home');


  };

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.12345,-70.54321);
    console.log('home ctrl');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
    var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: compiled[0]
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Marker location'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    $scope.map = map;
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
    if(!$scope.map) {
      return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };

  $scope.clickTest = function() {
    alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
  };

});
```

```css
/* Empty. Add your own CSS if you like */
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  height: 100%;
}

#search-input {
  text-align: center;
}
#search-bar {
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  top: 44px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 40;
}
#search-bar .item {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Sign-in, Then Tabs Example</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- google maps javascript -->
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true"></script>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  </head>


  <body>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="templates/sign-in.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Sign-In">
        <ion-content>
          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Username</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Password</span>
              <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="padding">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signIn(user)">
              Sign-In
            </button>
            <p class="text-center">
              <a href="#/forgot-password">Forgot password</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/forgot-password.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Forgot Password">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>
            Yeah this is just a demo showing how views can be shown without tabs, then you can navigate
            to views within tabs. Additionally, only one set of tabs needs to be written for all of the different views that should go inside the tabs. (Compared to written the same tab links in the footer of every view that's in a tab.)
          </p>
          <p>
            There's no username/password, just click
            the Sign-In button back a the sign-in view.
          </p>
          <p>
            Return to <a href="#/sign-in">Sign-In</a>.
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view>
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

          <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
            <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>

          <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/about">
            <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>

          <ion-tab title="Sign-Out" icon="ion-log-out" href="#/sign-in">
          </ion-tab>

        </ion-tabs>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template" >
         <ion-view view-title="Map">
        <div id="title">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" >
          <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        </div>

        <div id="search-bar">
          <div class="item item-input-inset">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper" id="search-input">
              <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ion-content>
          <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
        </ion-content>
        <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
          <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
        </ion-footer-bar>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Facts">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
          <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
          <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
          <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
          <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
          <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
          <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
          <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
          <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
          <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="About">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
          <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
          <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console ?

Comment: No there is no error on the console

Comment: Does the page not load or just the map ? can u see the tabs ?

Comment: only the map does not load. The tab loads

Comment: Add a `timeout` function on the google maps inititalize should fix it.

Comment: can you elaborate or provide sample code for your suggestion? I am very new to angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue.

I had to add the following line in HomeTabCtrl

```
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    initialize();
  });
```

This has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[$scope.$evalAsync()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) will solve your issue when you change your state or location.

```
$scope.signIn = function(user) {
   console.log('Sign-Innnn', user);
   $state.go('tabs.home');
   $scope.$evalAsync()
};
```

Comment: I tried adding  $scope.$evalAsync()  but it didn't help. Still I need to do page refresh to load the map

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the reload of the state:

```
$state.go('tabs.home', {}, {reload: true})
```

Comment: This didn't help too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
       initialize();
     }, 10)
 });
```

I'm still not sure if this will solve your problem. if it didn't try creating a jsfiddle with the issue.

Comment: Tried this too. But this also didn't help